# Deleting old records in sqlite database android

Tags: android, sqlite

Table must always store not more then 25 records. It means when I insert new array of records, I must control total number of records and if it's more then 25, it's necessary to remove some old. (table has integer primary key & text field datetime of inserting). How can I manage it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you just need the algorithm

1. Insert your new records
2. Select all entries ordered by date and check if the result has more than 25 entries
3. If it has, get the date of the 25th. entryLast
4. Delete all entries that are older entryLast

Answer (score 1):

for this you can use id to monitor if it crosses 25 then you should delete the rows as per `increasedNo - 25`. You can add this id to delete the rows from you `db`.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Vineet, just monitoring the id won't work if you don't specifically ask the db to renumber it's entries. It will just grow. 
I would use a limited db as what is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896457/limit-number-of-rows-returned-from-sqlite) and would check its size before deleting the oldest entry.