# Limit number of rows returned from sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-cursor

How can I limit the number of rows returned using activity.managedQuery()?

I am pretty sure there isn't a `limit` function in sqlite.  I also do not want to use [SQLiteDatabase.query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) because I am using URI to get my queries.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there IS a `limit` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497677/using-the-limit-statement-in-a-sqlite-query#2497689

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course there is LIMIT in SQLite. See the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html). For example:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM mytable WHERE foo = 'bar' LIMIT 42;
```